# best-case and worst-case running times in theta notation

Tags: pseudocode, big-o

I am not looking for the answer here but just how to find the worst/best case of the following problem (in theta notation); for loops are generally (theta(n)), which would make the best and worst case that but I think something else is going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Input: x (an integer), n (an integer)
addOnes(x, n) {
    if x > n then 
        for i <- 1 to n 
            return x + n
    else 
        for i <- x to n
                x <- x + n
    return x
```

Edit Answer:

Because of return x + n the constant (theta(1)) would be the best.

Best = (theta(1))
Worst = (theta(n))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two branches, and both are reachable. To find best and worst case complexity overall, find the best and worst case complexity of each loop, then the best case complexity overall is the better of the best case complexities for the two branches. Similar for the worst case complexity. And there's a small gotcha built into the problem for the naive to trip over, so be alert.

Comment: is that "gotcha" this line? return x + n, if so then if it was the constant (theta(1)) that would be the best case (because it would only iterate one time) and the worst case would still be (theta(n))

Comment: Edited first comment, I think I have it now.

Comment: Almost. Integers can also be negative, that is relevant.

Comment: Can you explain that further?

Comment: Since you have explicitly asked not to be given the solution, yes, and I'll try to leave the discovery to you. How many iterations exactly does the loop in the else-branch make (if it runs)? Can that number be much larger than `|n|`? When?

Comment: Until x >= n, I believe. How would a negative integer be calculated in the amount of times it would loop? (and I didn't want the answer right off hand, just trying to understand)

Comment: Don't think about until when the loop runs, calculate the exact number of iterations from the input. What happens if one or both of the inputs is negative? (And I know you didn't want the answer right off hand, you explicitly said so in your question. Very laudable. I am trying to nudge you to the eureka moment, therefore I'm rather roundabout.)

Comment: Well from the notes "A loop may run less than n times if it deals with more than one element on each pass." If less then theta(n) it would be logarithmic (according to the notes). If x is negative and n is positive then the else statement is executed. If they are both negative and x <= n then the else is executed as well. Then it runs x amount of times to n, with x being stored as x + n.

Comment: Ignore what the loop does. Just look at `for i <- x to n`. How many integers are there between `x` and `n` (both inclusive)?

Comment: integers x to n. Not really sure how to answer that. If x was 2 and n was 6 then 2,3,4,5,6. 2 steps then 3 steps then 4 steps, then 5 steps, then 6 steps, 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 20 steps

Comment: No, not 2 steps then 3 steps etc. Just 2,3,4,5,6: five numbers. If `x` is 2 and `n` is 6, the loop runs five times. If `x` is 0 and `n` is 12? Generally?

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself there. So how can we loop negative times? If x was -1 and n was 3, (-1,0,1,2,3) just loop normally 5 times? and 0 to 12 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) 13 times.

Comment: One doesn't loop negative times. But the loop variable `i` may have negative values. And yes, 5 and 13 are correct. And if `x = -1000`, `n = 7`?

Comment: No, 2 to 6 was 5, but `|2| + |6| + 1 = 9`. But we're coming close. (and `|x| + |n| + 1` is an upper bound, but may be way too large).

Comment: |n - x| + 1 seems to check out for all examples that come to my head.

Comment: Right. So there must also occur an `x` in the theta.

Comment: Well, not quite sure how to write that in theta. But I'm guessing that would be the upward bound or the worst case of the whole function.